# call function of object on top of stack in c#

Tags: c#, stack

What I want to accomplish is to access a method off an object that is at the top of a stack like so:

```
var stack = new Stack();
var obj1 = new Foo(stack); //has method called Bar, and reference to stack
stack.Push(obj1);
stack.Peek().Bar();
```

I want to use a stack instead of an array because the function Bar will pop itself off the stack at the end of its execution. Is there any way of doing this with a stack or will I need to result to a List? I thought Peek returns the top of the stack without popping.

Comment: your question is not clear.

Comment: I'm essentially pushing an object onto a stack and then wanting to access a method belonging to that object on the stack. So if the object on the top of the stack has a "Print method" I want to be able to say stack.Peek().Print();

Comment: Yes? If you use the generic version of Stack, Stack<T>, you might have better luck.

Comment: Using the Generic version worked. I'm not sure how to check your comment as an answer haha. But if you post a response I can check it as the answer. Thanks so much!

Comment: Nice catch on the generic thing--I did specifically link the generic version of Stack.  At the time, I didn't know how to use inline code markdown to say `Stack<T>` :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See [msdn resource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3278tedw.aspx) .

`Stack<T>` supports `Push()`, `Peek()` and `Pop()`.

Or perhaps I am not understanding your question.

Comment: I'm essentially pushing an object onto a stack and then wanting to access a method belonging to that object on the stack. So if the object on the top of the stack has a "Print method" I want to be able to say stack.Peek().Print(); Since peek returns the object on the top of the stack

Comment: Sure, ja, you betcha, nothing wrong with that.  `Peek()` returns a reference to an object.  You can call methods through the reference.  The fact that the object is also referenced in the stack is important.

Comment: Thanks! It turned out I had to use the generic version of stack

Comment: Oh yeah--avoid the non-generic collections like the plague!